# Why can't I call the second function in my custom hook from App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement AsyncStorage in a React Native app. I wrote a custom hook to handle all the logic to do with saving to and reading from AsyncStorage.

The first custom function, `saveData`, works a charm. The second one, `readData`, is proving quite difficult to use. None of the `console.log`s that I've inserted in the function are showing up in my terminal, so it isn't being used even though it is being called accurately (or at least, I am 99% sure it's being called accurately) in the `useEffect` in `App.js`, which is my application's entry point.

I can see that, on `line 12` in `App.js`, `currentLanguage` is a Promise. You can see, in the commented-out code, where I've handled the data such that I actually can read the stored language in AsyncStorage, which is my goal. But what I want to do is:

- have all the logic concerned with reading and saving data in my custom hook. At the moment, I can only read the data from within `App.js`, which isn't what I want.

I would really appreciate ideas on how I can move the logic around so that I don't have to handle the Promise from `App.js`, and can instead handle it from within the `readData` function in `useLocalStorage.js`.

Here's the code for my custom hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default () => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

  const saveData = async (key, data, callback) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data).then(() => {
        console.log('DATA HERE ---->', data);
        console.log('KEY from SAVEDATA HERE -->', key);
        if (callback) {
          callback(data);
        }
        return data;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setErrorMessage('Language selection storage error');
      if (callback) {
        callback(null);
      }
      return null;
    }
  };

  const readData = async (key, callback) => {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      console.log('VALALAL', value);
      if (value !== null) {
        console.log('stored value: ', value);
        if (callback) {
          callback(value);
        }
        return value;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, 'error');
      if (callback) {
        callback(null);
      }
      return null;
    }
  };

  return [saveData, errorMessage, readData];
};
```

Here's the code in my `App.js`:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './src/config/navigation';
import useLocalStorage from './src/hooks/useLocalStorage';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default () => {
  const [readData] = useLocalStorage();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('read data useEffect is running');
    const currentLanguage = readData('@selected_language');
    console.log('current language returned in useEffect: ', currentLanguage);
    // try {
    //   AsyncStorage.getItem('@selected_language').then((value) => {
    //     if (value !== null) {
    //       console.log('stored value: ', value);
    //     }
    //   });
    // } catch (e) {
    //   console.log(e, 'error');
    // }
  }, []);

  return <Navigation />;
};
```

All help very gratefully received!

Comment: If something is async, you can't ignore it somewhere else, you need to deal with async everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [readData] = useLocalStorage();
```

You're only accessing the first element of the array, which is the `saveData` function (despite what you named the variable). `readData` is the third.

```
const [saveData, error, readData] = useLocalStorage();
```

Alternatively, if you want to access the functions by their name, you'll need to change your hook to return an object instead of an array:

```
// At the end of the hook:
return { saveData, errorMessage, readData };

// In your component:
const { readData } = useLocalStorage();
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you! It's working a charm, and your tip is very helpful. I'm thrilled! Thank you!

Comment: You can also ignore some values when destructuring an array: `const [,, readData] = /**/` though an object is way clearer.